# Pisano period upper-bound for Tribonacci (3 step Fibonacci)

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

For the Pisano Period of a 2-step Fibonacci at modulo $n$ a common and simple upper bound, according to [this](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~tmk/Openproblems.pdf)  list of open problems, is $n^2-1$. Is there a similar upper bound for the Pisano Period of the Tribonacci (3-step Fibonacci) at modulo $n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $n^3-1$.

Consider any constant-coefficient linear recursion of order $m$.  The values mod $n$ are determined by any $m$-tuple of consecutive values mod $n$.  There are $n^m$ possible $m$-tuples mod $n$, but if $(0,\ldots, 0)$ occurs the other terms would have to be all $0$.  Thus if the sequence is nontrivial there are at most $n^m-1$ distinct possible $m$-tuples, and so the period will have to be at most $n^m-1$.

Comment: Do you know if this bound is sharp in general? I know it's sharp if $n = p$ is prime; then you can consider a recurrence with characteristic polynomial the minimal polynomial of a generator of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$.

Comment: No, it won't be sharp.  Suppose $n = p q$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime.  Then the sequence mod $p$ has period at most $p^m-1$ and the sequence mod $q$ has period at most $q^m-1$, so the sequence mod $pq$ has period at most $(p^m-1)(q^m-1) < (pq)^m - 1$.